# How Application Servers recognize users with Stateful beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I know a little about how Stateful beans work, about the passivatiang and activating state in beans, but I'm not sure how it really works..

I send a simple HTTP request to HttpServlet instance. There is no authentication or authorization services in my simple application. Appliation Server start a thread to handle my request. Than there is created a Stateful bean for this request which do something and this thead for handling request should be killed.

After one minute I send request again (Cacheless mode) and the same Stateful bean is delegated to handle my request. I'm wondering about HOW APPLICATION SERVER recognize me?

Maybe this is because of browser? HTTP protocol has a "connection keep-alive" mode. Application Server recognize me because browser open a multiconnection TCP handler and Application Server has a session with a browser?

Please explain me how AS recognize user when there is no authentication or authorization services and we used a HttpServlets which are stateless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Servlet containers maintain a "session" for each user, even when no authentication service is involved.  Generally speaking, HTTP requests are associated with the correct session either via cookies or via URL rewriting -- the latter typically meaning that a query parameter or REST-style request URI echoed by the client back to the server provides a session identifier.  In a secure (i.e. HTTPS) service, requests can also be associated with sessions via the SSL context.

Your stateful bean is most likely associated with the user session, not with an identifier of the user himself.  Among other things, note that this means even when a user authentication service is in place, the same user may have multiple distinct, active sessions at the same time, from the same client computer or different ones.

Comment: Thank you. So ASs recognize me because of "session" even if there is no authentication service. But there is no any visible cookies in this connection. How Servlet Container knows about me?

Comment: `HTTP requests are associated with the correct session either via cookies **or via URL rewriting**` means that the sessionid may be added as a URL parameter instead of using a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

In browser, you can see **JSESSIONID** as cookie, which is used to keep track the user session. 
For more details, google JSESSIONID.